# run shiny app for specified amount of time

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I want to run a shinyApp only for like a hour and then I want my app to stop automatically running instead of hand-clicking on the red STOP button in Rstudio.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `invalidateLater` and `stopApp`.

The variable `now` is defined outside the server function, so it will execute at startup and capture the start time.

This example re-executes the observer every 1000 milliseconds and tests if the new `Sys.time()` is bigger than the Starttime (`now`) plus 10 seconds. To change it to 1 hour, you have to exchange `now + 10` with `now + 3600`. And you could also increase invalidateLater to 30 minutes (`invalidateLater(1800000)`) for example.

After 10 seconds, it jumps into the if conditon and stops the App.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("test", "test", 1, 100, 1, 1)
)

now <- Sys.time()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    print(paste("Actual Time: ", Sys.time(), " - Endtime: ", now + 10))
    if (Sys.time() > now + 10) {
      print("Stop the App")
      stopApp()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```